# Bootstrap carousel control has more shadow down

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I just started to learn Bootstrap but I faced a strange problem with carousel [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOdlu.jpg)

Comment: Please reproduce the code you are using here.  Also, add a description of the problem.  The link is helpful, but only for as long as it remains active. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information on how to compose a Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've set a height to the entire carousel or just the images themselves make sure you change the height of the `.carousel-control` class. 
Or you can set the carousel controls to not have a background.

```
.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
  background-image: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, You're Awesome :)

I used
.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
  background-image: none;
}

and works perfectly